# How to show idle time in minutes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, idle-timer

I am trying to code an application that detects user activity. If the user is idle for five minutes or so, the computer will shut down. I can show idle time in a label but I can only do it in milliseconds. I want to show it in minutes, it'd be really helpful if someone can give me some information about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why does the computer shut down after five minutes of inactivity? You should investigate and fix that issue first.

Comment: It's the feature of the application. Computer shuts down if the user is inactive for a long period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have the idle time in milliseconds, why not just convert it?

```
idleMinutes = idleMilliseconds / 60000;
```

Comment: Yes! I thought so too.. Thank you.